# Toast inside onclick recyclerview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm making an app in which an activity shows a recyclerview. I'm trying to get a toast when the item in the list is clicked. I've seen the various solutions on StackOverflow and they don't help.

**BasicsAdapter.java**

```
public class BasicsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BasicsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Basic> basicsList;

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        public TextView title;

        public MyViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }

    public BasicsAdapter(List<Basic> basicsList){
        this.basicsList = basicsList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.basic_list_row, parent, false);

        itemView.setClickable(true);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(true);
        //itemView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); //dont enable this

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Basic basic = basicsList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(basic.getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return basicsList.size();
    }
}
```

**basics_list.java**

```
public class basics_list extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private List<Basic> basicList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private BasicsAdapter mAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle(R.string.basics_list_name);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_basics_list);

        // Adding Toolbar to Main screen

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        /*ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager); */

        // set recycler view

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mAdapter = new BasicsAdapter(basicList);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        prepareBasicsData();

        // Create Navigation drawer and inflate layout
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

// Adding menu icon to Toolbar
        ActionBar supportActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (supportActionBar != null) {
            supportActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
            supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

// Set behavior of Navigation drawer
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        // Set item in checked state
                        menuItem.setChecked(true);
                        // TODO: handle navigation
                        // Closing drawer on item click
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    }
                });


    }

    private void prepareBasicsData() {
        Basic basic = new Basic("Introduction to Linux");
        basicList.add(basic);

        basic = new Basic("What is The Terminal");
        basicList.add(basic);

        basic = new Basic("Programmers guide");
        basicList.add(basic);

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your Toast message in your code?

Comment: I removed it. None that I tried worked. getApplicationContext or getBaseContext is invalid. Using the activity with "this" didn't work

Comment: Just add `Context` as one of the Constructors of your class, and when you initialize the class from your Activity, pass "this" and you'll have the context.

Comment: @AndroidNFC Ye, already mentioned it in my *answer*.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot On such questions, where there is no clear distinction what the user is actually inquiring for, I answer posibilities in comments, to avoid answers that do not belong to the actual question. Might mislead readers in years to come.

Comment: I know, but I think his question was clear enough : )

Answer (score 19):

Use `itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {})` instead of `itemView.setOnClickListener(true)`.

This way you apply an `OnClickListener` directly. It would look similar to this:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void OnClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Item is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

And you might put it into the constructor.

Comment: Actually he has a view reference, and can get context from it,  so why for he needs an activity?

Comment: Also why for you need to set listener inside onCreateViewHolder(), just do this inside the view holder constructor.

Comment: Minor edit for above "LENGHT.SHORT":  use "Toast.LENGTH_SHORT" instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just set your `OnClickListener` within your `ViewHolder`.

public class BasicsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private List<Basic> basicsList;

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    public TextView title;

    public MyViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Item is clicked", LENGHT.SHORT).show();
        });
        title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    }

}

public BasicsAdapter(List<Basic> basicsList){
    this.basicsList = basicsList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.basic_list_row, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Basic basic = basicsList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(basic.getTitle());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return basicsList.size();
}
}
```

Comment: Minor edit for above "LENGHT.SHORT":  use "Toast.LENGTH_SHORT" instead.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

```
public class BasicsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BasicsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<Basic> basicsList;

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
    Context context;

    public MyViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);
        title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    }
}

public BasicsAdapter(Context context,List<Basic> basicsList){
    this.context=context;
    this.basicsList = basicsList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.basic_list_row, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Basic basic = basicsList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(basic.getTitle());
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
       Toast.makeText(context,"Show your text here",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return basicsList.size();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you, I hope.
He had used an interface to listen to the click of the view in ViewHolder.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCSePoE3lqA

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with Kotlin:

In the inner class ...ViewHolder(...)

```
fun myFunction(data: Data){
        binding.item.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText( it.context,"Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
}
```